# Capturing limited historical data in dbt snapshot

Tags: dbt

We have a DBT snapshot which runs daily and checks for the columns to expire existing data and then insert the latest data to snapshot table. Since the snapshot runs daily, data is growing exponentially in snapshot table and we want to limit the historical changes based on subset of columns and at the same time capture the latest data from dbt model to snapshot.

Consider below example

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-02 |
| A | B | X | D | 2023-06-02 | 2023-06-03 |
| A | Y | X | D | 2023-06-03 | 2023-06-04 |
| A | Z | X | D | 2023-06-04 | null |

column2 and column3 are check columns in config block as shown below

```
 {{
    config(
      target_schema='snapshots',
      strategy='check',
      unique_key='column1',
      check_cols=['column2', 'column3'],
    )
}}
```

Now snapshots are working as expected. Our requirement is to check the columns column2 and column3 and update the snapshot regularly but skip capturing the history on column2 changes because data in column2 is changing very frequently and due to this the table volume is growing and the downstream applications are facing challenges to retrieve data from this snapshot table. If any changes in column3 we need to capture the history of these changes because downstream applications want this information.

Output should look something like this

on 2023-06-03 the data in snapshot should be like

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-02 |
| A | B | X | D | 2023-06-02 | 2023-06-03 |
| A | Y | X | D | 2023-06-03 | null |

on 2023-06-04 the data in snapshot should be like

| column1 | column2 | column3 | column4 | dbt_valid_from | dbt_valid_to |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | B | C | D | 2023-06-01 | 2023-06-02 |
| A | B | X | D | 2023-06-02 | 2023-06-03 |
| A | Z | X | D | 2023-06-03 | null |

so ideally if there is any change on column2 we should have latest data captured from model but it should not contain snapshot history. Is there a way to achieve this using dbt snapshot.

Comment: What you are asking for is not a snapshot so you cannot use dbt snapshots to achieve that. What you actually want is a snapshot that tracks ONLY column3 and a separate model (table or incremental depending on how big it is) that represents the current state of the source including column2. Then you can combine those to produce an output like the one you want.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths Thanks, this information helps. I wanted to check if we have in built functionality for this requirement. I will follow the steps you mentioned